# Определение пути и направления движения курсора за заданный интервал времени

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо определить изменение положения курсора за n промежуток времени и если пройдена n дистанция в промежутке заданных направлений, то выполнять какое-то действие.
В js'e только начинаю разбираться по этому сильно не ругать за код.
Теоретически вроде понял как сделать, а на практике не очень получается.
Насколько понял мне нужно определить текущее положение курсора и новое через заданный промежуток времени, найти вектор его длину и угол, и проверить на соответствие.

Upd: вот вроде все получилось, правильно считает, но не пойму почему отрицательные градусы получаются.

```js
var lastX = 0;
var lastY = 0;
var angle = 0,
  distance = 0,
  deg = 0;
var lastTime = new Date();

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {

  var now = new Date();
  if ((now - lastTime) >= 100) {

    var mx = event.clientX;
    var my = event.clientY;
    var vx = mx - lastX;
    var vy = my - lastY;
    angle = Math.atan2(vy, vx);
    distance = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);
    deg = (angle * 180) / Math.PI;
    var disF = distance.toFixed();
    var degF = deg.toFixed();

    lastX = mx;
    lastY = my;
    lastTime = now;

    $(".output").text(disF + ", " + degF);

  }
});
```

```css
.output {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="output"></span>
```

[image: Величины углов]

Answer (score 1):

```js
var lastX = 0;
var lastY = 0;
var angle = 0, distance = 0;
var lastTime = new Date();

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {

  var now = new Date();
  if ((now - lastTime) >= 500) {
    
    var mx = event.clientX;
    var my = event.clientY;
    var vx = mx - lastX;
    var vy = -(my - lastY);
    angle = Math.atan2(vy, vx);
    distance = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy);

    lastX = mx;
    lastY = my;
    lastTime = now;
    
    $("#display").text(distance.toFixed(2) + ", " + angle.toFixed(3));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="display"></span>
```

*Update*

Добавил минус перед выражением `var vy = -(my - lastY);`. Он нужен из-за того, что экранная ось Y направлена вниз.

Comment: не подскажешь еще, относительно чего данная функция Math.atan2 формирует ось Х, почему при движении мышки в правую сторону и вверх получаются значения из 2 четверти (выше прикрепил изображение, ориентируюсь по нему) иногда отрицательные, наверно нужно с интервалом поэкспериментировать. И есть ли какая функция для перевода радиан в градусы?

Comment: @kost1k Добавил в ответ.